# Make transparent color bar with height 0 in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a 3d bar chart showing the network bandwidth of two 3 regions. I want to make the bars with 0 height transparent in matplotlib. In my output they are getting colors forming a square with height 0.

How can i do that?

Code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

data = np.array([
[1000,200],
[100,1000],
])

column_names = ['','Oregon','', 'Ohio','']
row_names = ['','Oregon','', 'Ohio']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

lx= len(data[0])            # Work out matrix dimensions
ly= len(data[:,0])

xpos = np.arange(0,lx,1)    # Set up a mesh of positions
ypos = np.arange(0,ly,1)
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xpos+0.25, ypos+0.25)

xpos = xpos.flatten()   # Convert positions to 1D array
ypos = ypos.flatten()
zpos = np.zeros(lx*ly)

dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = data.flatten()

cs = ['r', 'g'] * ly

ax.bar3d(xpos,ypos,zpos, dx, dy, dz, color=cs)

ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(column_names)
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(row_names)
ax.set_zlabel('Mb/s')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `alpha` parameter you can set for transparency which is a bit hidden in the documentation of `bar3d` since it is contained in the `**kwargs` available from [`mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection).

However there is not yet a possibility to give an array of `alpha` values for each individual bar as e.g. for the `color` key. Hence, you have to plot the transparent and not transparent ones separately with help of a mask for example.

```
# needs to be an array for indexing
cs = np.array(['r', 'g', 'b'] * ly)

# Create mask: Find values of dz with value 0
mask = dz == 0

# Plot bars with dz == 0 with alpha
ax.bar3d(xpos[mask], ypos[mask], zpos[mask], dx[mask], dy[mask], dz[mask],
         color=cs[mask], alpha=0.2)
# Plot other bars without alpha
ax.bar3d(xpos[~mask], ypos[~mask], zpos[~mask], dx[~mask], dy[~mask], dz[~mask],
         color=cs[~mask])
```

This gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. How you adjusted the size of the graph? i mean when i save the plot using plt.savefig() , my z axis label gets cut-off

Comment: I saved the figure by hand. If you do it programmatically try `plt.tight_layout()` before `plt.savefig()`.